# Creating a stopwatch in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, time, stopwatch

Does anyone know if there is a way to create a stopwatch in MS Access? I'm looking for a way to have a stopwatch "start" at the point that someone clicks "new" record for a particular form, and have the stopwatch "end" at the point the person saves the information entered in the form? Ideally, for each record in the table, I would like to have an additional column displaying the time it took to create the form.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: I'm curious what is the purpose of tracking the amount of time it takes your users to insert each new record?

Comment: Do you want the timer resolution in seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, picoseconds.?

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325238) You could set the onClick to "new" and you can put in a simple if statement to allow it to stop on the save action

Answer (score 2):

When you click the *new* button, the form's `On Current` event will fire.  You can distinguish whether the current record is a new or existing record by examining the form's `NewRecord` property.

I added a Long Integer field named `seconds_for_insert` to my table.  Then I created a form whose record source is a query based on that table.  The form includes a text box name `txtSeconds_for_insert` which is bound to the record source `seconds_for_insert` field.  Here is my form's code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Dim blnNewRecord As Boolean
Dim dteStartTime As Date

Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.txtSeconds_for_insert = DateDiff("s", dteStartTime, Now())
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
    blnNewRecord = Me.NewRecord
    If blnNewRecord Then
        dteStartTime = Now()
    End If
End Sub
```

If your source table contains an autonumber field, Access will save the new record as soon as you type anything into one of the bound controls.  Any remaining data you add to that "new" record will be saved with an update rather than an insert operation.  So in that situation, use `Form_BeforeUpdate` instead of `Form_BeforeInsert`.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If blnNewRecord Then
        Me.txtSeconds_for_insert = DateDiff("s", dteStartTime, Now())
    End If
End Sub
```

The `txtSeconds_for_insert` text box doesn't have to be enabled or even visible for this to work.  You may prefer to set Visible = No to avoid distracting the users, or if you don't want them to know you're tracking that information.